# WMS layer connects but layer is blank (Australian MODIS vegetation cover using QGIS)

Tags: qgis, wms

I've been trying to connect a vegetation WMS layer to QGIS, which seems to work fine when I connect the WMS in the data source manager, however the layer seems to be blank.

Specifically, I'm trying to connect this layer here:

[image: GEOGLAM RAPP]

from this website: https://map.geo-rapp.org/, using this WMS URL: http://gsky.nci.org.au/ows/geoglam

For reference, this is what I see on my screen:

[image: my QGIS screen]

Still a bit of a GIS novice so not really sure how to go about fixing this problem, but couldn't find anything online.

Comment: the WCS method works as described here https://nci-data-training.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_notebook/gsky/GSKY_QGIS.html (QGIS 3.22)

Comment: It is a time enabled layer and GetCapabilities seems to be right. For some reason I could not get QGIS to make correct GetMap requests with `&time=...`. The service seems to require times up till milliseconds + Z https://gsky.nci.org.au/ows/geoglam?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=modis_fract_cov_monthly&STYLES=&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&FORMAT=image/png&CRS=EPSG:4326&DPI=144&MAP_RESOLUTION=144&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:144&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&BBOX=60.437623,24.152868,60.467882,24.183127&time=2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z.

Comment: @Mapperz, thank you so much for the help! The process in the document you supplied worked well - didn't realise it would have to be added as WCS as opposed to WMS. Only issue now is that the pixel size as WCS in QGIS is significantly larger than in GEOGLAM. Additionally, the link you supplied no longer seem to work for me:)